# How to distinct fast single row in table?. If is there any hint?

Tags: sql

My table having 500 rows .Iam tried to distinct the row values.but it will take time .if there any tuning this process and consume the time.

Comment: Operations on 500 rows using any reasonable database on any reasonable hardware will take little time.  When you are getting started with SQL, you shouldn't worry about performance problems until you actually encounter them.

Comment: What is meant by distinct single row? Do you have duplicates and what to get rid of them? or are you looking for a specific row? If the first - look about `distinct`

Comment: Here having lot duplicates .so iam tried to distinct the value it will take lot of time so thats y iam asking is there tuning hints?

Comment: @rangaswamy:provide sample table data and schema of the table

Answer (score 0):

Although initally you will always have to invest time when doing a sql query on a large table, there are ways to reduce this when performing same operation repeatedly within your application. Such as chacheing (saving the returned rows in memory) or PDO prepared statements.